# Filling in model when separating parts

Tags: modeling, mesh

I have created a head... It has hair and flat eye.

I have now separated the hair and eye from model and parented it to the head.

1. Do I need to fill in under the eye and under the hair?
2. should I and can I hide the faces inside the model that you don't see?

Comment: You can do whatever you want with your model. The only thing that matters is the comfort with which you will then edit your model. If those mesh parts won't be seen in the final render or etc. and you don't need them to affect any kind of source, that of course you don't have to fill them if there is no particular need.

Comment: I think the question is, as I have separated the hair from the face, it opens up the head under it. I see other blender models they have closed off under the hair and eyes. So wondering as it is hollow do I need to close it off from not bleeding out.

Comment: Can you add a screenshot to your question, please

Comment: I will try and add a picture, however basically the question is, does the mesh need to be closed when you seperate a part.

I modelled a character in full. So created a Face with eyes/mouth/ears/hair all in one model.

I have seperated features with "P" and parented them to the face. Now I have done this, I want to know if I need to Fill the parts that are not whole.

Comment: If it doesn't affect the final look, no, if it does, fill it

Comment: Amazing thank you.

I needed to know if all Meshes need to be fully wrapped. It won't ever be seen no, however it is still a "open" mesh with seperated objects.

I have seen other models from creators where they have fully closed all their meshes, so I thought it is best practice or a Must to do this.